# Can't load CartoDB Map Academy files

Tags: carto

I've been trying to do the very intro CartoDB Map Academy course, but when I try to load the example files – e.g., http://acdmy.org/d/counties.zip – I get a screen that says "Downloading file" forever and eventually it just fails and I later get an email telling me that it couldn't import my table, without any more details. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Are you importing the zip file without unzipping it?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried just copying and pasting the `http://acdmy.org/d/counties.zip` URL into CartoDB and it imported fine the us_counties table. I also downloaded locally the zip file and imported it without problems (no need to unzip, CartoDB unzips automatically, also being a Shapefile it is a requirement to use a zipped file).

Maybe was a temporal file download issue... If still happens to you please provide as many details as possible to try to pinpoint or reproduce it.